# print in-order binary search tree with parentheses

Tags: c, tree

I have made a recursive function that print a tree in-order

```
void print_tree(TREE_TYPE eType,Tree* root) {
    if (eType == TREE_TYPE_INT)
        print1(TREE_TYPE_INT, root);

    if (eType == TREE_TYPE_CHAR)
        print1(TREE_TYPE_INT, root);
}

void print_element(TREE_TYPE eType, void* data) {
    if (eType == TREE_TYPE_INT) {
        printf("(%d)", *((int*)data));
    } else if (eType == TREE_TYPE_CHAR) {
        printf("(%c)", *((char*)data));
    }
}

void print1(TREE_TYPE eType, Tree* root) {
    if (root == NULL)
        return;

    if (root->left) {
        print1(eType, root->left);
        printf("<");
    }
    print_element(eType, root->data);

    if (root->right) {
        printf(">");
        print1(eType, root->right);
    }

}
```

Now I have to add parentheses in the following way for a tree with 2,3,8 to print the outcome: ((2)<(3)>(8))
but when 7 is added to the tree to print it as following: ((2)<(3)>((7)<(8))).
It is like every tree with at least one node have to be in parentheses.
Is there a way to do it recursively?

Comment: `"((2)<(3)>((7)<(8)))"` is a strange result (un-balanced `<>`).  Are you _certain_ this is exactly the desired output?

Comment: @chux by the op's stated goal, there is no guaranteed "balance" in `<>`, ex: if a tree has children on only one side. I'm still lost on what the *problem* is, however, as the OP's output at-least appears to be right if I understood the goal.

Comment: @WhozCraig Yes, I too hope OP explains more. Example: "2,3,8" is a list, not a tree, Many different trees could have elements of "2,3,8".   Although I am confident that "add parentheses" means "add parentheses and angle brackets".

Comment: Ok, *now* I get the question. The `((2)<(3)>((7)<(8)))` is the *goal*, and this code *doesn't* do that. (duh). I understand the output though. you gotta stare awhile =P

Comment: sorry for the lack of information, < and > sate if it is a left (<) node or a right node (>)

Answer (score 0):

You can 'surround' the code in your `print1` function with the two parentheses, and the check for null, like this:

```
if (root->left || root->right) printf("(");
```